# In order to obtain the size of ELF binary, what's the difference between size and ls?

Tags: linux, elf

Test is on 32bit x86 Linux.

In order to get the size of some ELF binaries, I tried these two commands:

```
ls -la sha512sum
size sha512sum
```

But the thing is that the size output are different:

```
ls -la sha512sum
-rwxrwxr-x 1 szw175 szw175 95856 Oct 10 07:50 sha512sum

 size sha512sum
 text      data     bss     dec     hex filename
 89644      488     452   90584   161d8 sha512sum
```

So my question is, in order to evaluate the size of an ELF binary, which method is more reliable? Why are these two methods different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size(1)` tells you the sizes of the various sections within the file. `ls(1)` tells you the number of bytes the ELF file contains. They serve completely different purposes, and which one is more "reliable" depends completely upon what you're going to do with the file.

Comment: Then could you tell me why are the two sizes different?

Comment: Because the file contains more than just the contents of the sections.

Comment: Yes.. I mean.. this is what I am confused about, besides sections, what else does `ELF` file contain?

Comment: Headers. Symbol tables. Everything else you need to load and/or link and/or debug an ELF.

Answer (score 0):

You could think of a elf-file contain various information about loading & linking the program at runtime. All information that is given as input (.text, .data, .bss, .rel.*, etc.) all are stored in various sections of the elf-file. These section are managed by a section-header table stored somewhere in the binary.

You get the size of contents of the sections by

```
size sha512sum
```

but, if you want to get the total size of the file (which includes along with section contents - elf-header, program-header table, and section-header table), then  you will use

```
ls -la sha512sum
```

Note that when the program is loaded (at any address, namely base address), the contents of the sections are mapped at various offsets  from the base address. The mapping may not be continous and the runtime-image of the program may be larger than the file-size. Also, note that some sections (like .bss which only contain zeros) are not even stored in the file. The program-loader maps a memory-region and fills zeros in them, instead of copying zeros from the file. This saves alot of disk space & reduces file size (and thus, the time to load the binary into memory).

So, the memory-image size of the program could be larger than the file-size.